# C store user string in an array to access

Tags: c, arrays

Hey guys I am trying to create a function that takes my cmdstring and stores each value into an array. Right now my program takes user input and then everything seperated by a space will be printed out as it's own string. For example when the program ran it will give this prompt ":" Then the user can enter a string.. and when entered it prints each individual string like this:

:dog cat box

dog  /n
cat /n
box /n

How do I store each different string into an array so I can access them and say something like 
if token[0] == dog { do something... Here is my code ...

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  char cmdString[MAX_CHARS + 1];
  char *token;
  while (true) {

    printf(": ");
    scanf(" %s",&cmdString);
    token = strtok(cmdString," ");
    while(token!=NULL) {

      printf(" %s\n", token);
      token = strtok(NULL," ");

    }

}
```

Comment: Make an array: `char *tokens[100];`

Comment: BTW, `if (token[0] == "dog")` doesn't work. You need to use `strcmp` to compare strings.

Comment: Each time `strtok` gives you a non-NULL pointer, instead of calling `printf` on it, store it in the next cell of the array (declared as suggested by user3386109).

Comment: By the way, another way of calling `strtok` (and the way I've always imagined it was intended to be called) is in a `for` loop: `for(token = strtok(cmdString, " "); token != NULL; token = strtok(NULL, " "))`